# How to sort the following from highest rank to the lowest

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to understand how to use Collections.sort and Collections.reverse and thought that I almost had it but sometimes, my ranking is not placed in order from the highest to the lowest... I have done a series of if statements and now sure if this is the best way to go about but have some weird sorting order problem. I tried to edit my database but it is not sorting it properly....

```java
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://medical-review-in-australia.firebaseio.com/")
  .getReference()
  .child("Medical Clinics")
  .child("Clinics"); // getReference() is the root  // can keep adding parents
```

```java
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        list.clear();

        popular_clinic_ranking = new ArrayList<>();


        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

             popular_clinics = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("ranking").child("ranking").getValue());



             if (popular_clinics.equals("[Super Sleuth]")) {

                popular_clinics_name = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("Postal Information").child("name").getValue());
                popular_clinics_score = snapshot.child("Postal Information").child("total_Score").getValue(Integer.class);


               
        

             }   if (popular_clinics.equals("[Master Detective]")) {

                popular_clinics_name = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("Postal Information").child("name").getValue());
                popular_clinics_score = snapshot.child("Postal Information").child("total_Score").getValue(Integer.class);

          
          

            }   if (popular_clinics.equals("[Senior Detective]")) {

                popular_clinics_name = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("Postal Information").child("name").getValue());
                popular_clinics_score = snapshot.child("Postal Information").child("total_Score").getValue(Integer.class);


        String txt;
        txt = "Medical Clinic: " + popular_clinics_name + "\n\nTotal Score: " + popular_clinics_score + "\n\nRanking: " + popular_clinics;




            list.add(txt);
            Collections.sort(list);
            Collections.reverse(list);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // need to use both Collections.sort and Collections.reveerse...
```

[image: App ui]

Now I am trying to store the information in the order of ranking and it seems to be working this way but not all the ranking are inserted into the database... Also, why is count returning 4 when I have 3 medical clinics under two parents? Is it counting one of my parents a child? Does it matter if I have capital letters or lower case when creating a child? I realised that a child has to be lowercase for it to work as a child?

```
 DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://medical-review-in-australia.firebaseio.com/").getReference().child("Medical Clinics").child("Clinics"); // getReference() is the root  // can keep adding parents
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list.clear();


                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    popular_clinics = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("ranking").child("ranking").getValue());
                    count = (int) snapshot.getChildrenCount() - 1;
                   
                    for(int i = 0; i<= count; i++) {

                        if (popular_clinics.equals("[Super Sleuth]")) {

                            popular_clinics_name = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("Postal Information").child("name").getValue());
                            popular_clinics_score = snapshot.child("Postal Information").child("total_Score").getValue(Integer.class);


                            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                            map.put("name", popular_clinics_name);
                            map.put("score", popular_clinics_score);
                            map.put("ranking", popular_clinics);

                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://medical-review-in-australia.firebaseio.com/").getReference().child("Medical Clinics").child("Popular Clinics").child("Super Sleuth").child("super sleuth").setValue(map);


                        }
```

Comment: What langauage are you using

Comment: Hello! I am using Java..

Comment: I am using listview though and read that I must use recycledview, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you are trying to sort numeric string values. and java has a stupid problem with that so for example if you have these values in your list:

"item 01"
"item 02"
"item 03"
"item 10"

after sorting the order will be something like this:

"item 01"
"item 10"
"item 02"
"item 03"

So one clean way would be to store your data in a class like so maybe:

```
public static class People {
    String name;
    int score;
    String ranking;

    public People(String name, int score, String ranking) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
        this.ranking = ranking;
    }
}
```

And then make an arrayList of People like so:

```
ArrayList<People> peopleInfo = new ArrayList<People>();
```

Then add your data to this arrayList and then sort it like this:

```
peopleInfo.sort(Comparator.comparing(info -> info.name));
```

Also note that this type of sorting is case-sensitive.

Comment: but my integers are not string though but I am sorting according to my arraylist, which is a string... the scores should not matter but my inspector should be higher than Gumshoe

Comment: tring txt;
        txt = "Medical Clinic: " + popular_clinics_name + "\n\nTotal Score: " + popular_clinics_score + "\n\nRanking: " + popular_clinics; this is how you are adding your values and I see popular_clinics_score  in the middle which means there is a number there converted to string

Comment: So I guess that this can't be done? and I will not proceed with it

Comment: it can be done and I have given you the link to an answer in my answer. did you check it out?

Comment: I just edited my answer and offered an easy solution. check it out.